# Sqlite long parameter bound as string with java 7, not with java 6

Tags: java, sqlite

I've got code that worked like a charm for years. It broke with a recent java update on my Mac.

- when using java 6 (1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609), it works as expected
- when using java 7 (1.7.0_60-b19), it doesn't work

Here's the test code:

```
PreparedStatement p = mConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT rowid, * FROM cases_customers WHERE case_id = ?");
p.setLong(1, 2);
ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
System.out.println("One result? " + r.next());

p = mConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT rowid, * FROM cases_customers WHERE case_id = ? + '0'");
p.setLong(1, 2);
r = p.executeQuery();
System.out.println("At least one result? " + r.next());
```

Output:

```
At least one result? false
At least one result? true
```

The second query forces the data to be bound as a number because of the addition. So even if the data is bound as long in the code, it somehow is translated as string later on.

I did not change my SQLite JDBC driver (which is xerial's 3.7.2).

I distribute this desktop app using Java Web Start, and the compilation/jar bundling is done 'manually' through a GNU make file that calls directly `javac` for compilation. The compiled jar/app is working as expected, I mean the above code outputs `true/true`.

Here's the build config:
[image: Build configuration: default with option to start on UI thread on Mac]

When running into the code, I end up in DB.java (from sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2), in the method `DB#sqlbind`:

```
else if (v instanceof Long) {
    return bind_long(stmt, pos, ((Long) v).longValue());
}
```

- in java 6, this `DB` abstract class implementation is in `NativeDB.java` and calls a *native* `bind_long`.
- in java 7, this `DB` abstract class implementation is in `NestedDB.java` and calls this:

.

```
@Override
synchronized int bind_long(long stmt, int pos, long v) throws SQLException {
    return bind_text(stmt, pos, Long.toString(v)); // TODO
}
```

This is where the `long` value is bound as a `String`.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: What do you mean? I stepped into every method, it's kept as a `Long` up to `DB#sqlbind`, which calls `bind_long`, itself using `Long.toString` with a beautiful `// TODO` on that line. Why does it work outside of AS, but doesn't in AS? Why does it work with AS 0.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of my analysis is in the question itself, see the edit history.

I was using an SQLite JDBC driver that used native code in java 6, and java code in java 7. The native code was working as expected, while the java code bound `long` values as `String`s. I updated my JDBC driver to a newer version, which uses native code in both java 6 and 7.

Now it's working fine.